# Linq-To-Sql database calls

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I couldn't find an answer to this. I'm sure the answer is simple, I don't think I was searching for the right thing.

I have a .dbml file with two tables: Employees and Departments. There's a relationship between the two, Employees has a DepartmentID.

Anyways, I'm doing this in my code:

```
Employee emp = Employee.Get(123);

string fname = emp.FirstName;
string lname = emp.LastName;
string deptName = emp.Department.Name;
string deptCode = emp.Department.Code;
```

What I'm wondering is, every time I call `emp.Department`, is that making a database call? Or was all that information loaded when I created the Employee object?

Comment: There is no way to know given what you have showed us.  Please show the code for Employee.Get and Empoyee.Department -- then we can tell.

Comment: imho, that the kind of things you should/could test by yourself. There are multiple ways to verify this : 1- use LinqPad, 2- put a trace on the SQL server, 3- break after your Get, before your fname = emp..., then change the value in the database or disable your network connection, 4- use the "go to definition" feature of VS on "FirstName" and dig a bit to see if it ever calls the DB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It made a trip to database, when you first accessed `emp.Department.Name` unless [deferred loading is turned off](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386920%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

It won't make another trip when you say `emp.Department.Code` in next statement, it would have already got the `Deparment` object in memory.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557830/does-linq-to-sql-automatically-lazy-load-associated-entities/557921#557921) explains it in more detail.

You may want to see

- [at what point does linq-to-sql or linq send a request to the database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2158882/277290)
- [Does linq to sql automatically lazy load associated entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/557830/277290)
- [Blog: Linq to SQL Deferred Loading - Lazy Load](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/10/06/linq-to-sql-deferred-loading-lazy-load.aspx)

Comment: Did it make another one when I said `emp.Department.Code`?

Comment: @Steven - I've modified my answer to answer your comment, and provide more details. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Steven: NO! Once L2S has loaded the dependent entity - it's loaded and ready to be used; no need to go back to the database again - and L2s won't do that. It will load the dependent entity **once**, when you first access any of its properties - once that's done - it's done.

Answer (score 0):

The query is only executed once to retrieve data. After that it is tracked within the context in memory.

You could verify this using SQL Profiler.